# Shorter version of Java System.out.println()

Tags: java, println, shorthand

Is there a way to shorthand `System.out.println()` as a method?

```
System.out.println() = short();
```

So I could change this main method to...

```
package Array;
import java.util.Random;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        data();
        a();
        random();
        a();
        array();
        a();
        rows();
        a();
        System.out.println("average " + average(45,15,15,48,97,45));

    }
    static void a() {System.out.println();}
    static void data() {
        int array[] = {1,5,6};
        int alength = array.length;
        System.out.println("  Location\tData");
        for(int i=0;i<alength;i++) {
            System.out.println("  " + i + "\t\t" + array[i]);
        }
    }
    static void random() {
        Random rdm = new Random();
        int freq[] = new int[7];

        for(int i=1;i<1000;i++) {
            ++freq[1+rdm.nextInt(6)];
        }
        System.out.println("Face\tFrequency");
        int frequence = freq.length;
        for(int face=1;face<frequence;face++) {
            System.out.println(face+"\t"+freq[face]);
        }
    }
    static void array() {
        String po[] = {"lala","po","tinkiwinki","disty"};
        for(String lala: po) {
            System.out.print(lala + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    static void rows() {
        int arrays[][]= {{1,5,78,15},{45,67},{875,15687,158,4515,23,2,2}};

        for(int i=0;i<arrays.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<arrays[i].length;j++) {
                System.out.print(arrays[i][j]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    static int average(int...numbers) {
        int total=0;
        for(int x:numbers)
            total += x;
        return total/numbers.length;
    }
}

class time {
    int h, m, s;
    void setTime(int hour,int minute,int second) {
        h = ((hour>=0 && hour<=24) ? hour : 0);
        m = ((minute>=0 && minute<=60) ? minute : 0);
        s = ((second>=0 && second<=60) ? second : 0);
    }
```

This main method

```
 public class Array {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            a(data());
            a(random());
            a(array());
            a(rows());
            a("average " + average(45,15,15,48,97,45));
```

It prints out this

```
      Location  Data
  0     1
  1     5
  2     6

Face    Frequency
1   154
2   186
3   161
4   168
5   179
6   151

lala po tinkiwinki disty 

1   5   78  15  
45  67  
875 15687   158 4515    23  2   2   

average 44
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? You're just delegating.

Comment: Doing so in Java 5/6/7 is likely going to make your code messier.

Comment: Why is this an improvement, isn't a() a completely seperate function from whatever you're passing to it? In that it prints a new line, which seems to be what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want a() to print a newline, then what's passed to it?

```
static void a(Callable<T> f) {
    System.out.println();
    f.call();
}
```

I think this should do it.

If you don't want to mess with Callable:

Instead of having your methods return void and printing, have them return String.

Then have a take a String as an argument and print the newline followed by the String passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Your code almost makes me cry.

But to the point, i'am not sure what your trying to achieve here.
I really dont see what wrong with System.out.println(); 
Try using a toString() method in your array class and try taking an object orientated approach.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can type `Syso` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> at the same time if you want to make it easier to type it.

Comment: ... or `sysout` instead of `syso`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Object Oriented practices :

- your data, random, array, etc. should a **Classes**
- classes with a custom **toString()** or a prettyPrint() method

So your aim is something like :

```
Data data = new Data();
System.out.println(data.toString());
```

But I'm not sure what the question is really about...